# How to vectorize this operation in numpy?

Tags: numpy, vectorization

I have a 2d array s and I want to calculate differences elementwise, i.e.:

[image]

Since it cannot be written as a single matrix multiplication, I was wondering what is the proper way to vectorize it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use broadcasting for that: `d = s[:, None, :] - s[None, :, :]`. Note the `None` enable you to create a new dimension. Numpy implicitly perform the broadcasting operation between the two arrays.